# publishing via citrix to building a web app

Tags: web-applications, citrix, xenapp

What are the merits and demerits to publishing apps via citrix xenapp vs building an app using web app and just giving users the URL ? 
I am looking for info in terms of 
1. performance
2. infrastructure
3. upgrade overheads
4. Cost.

i am doing a lot of research besides this forum but haven't found a good selling point to give an edge of one over the other. So looking to see if anyone has been in a similar  situation and had to make a business decision.

Answer (score 0):

Citrix is good for covering legacy use cases where you have existing apps and systems you need to integrate with. However if you're looking to create a brand new application I'd be looking at web apps first and then fallback to other options if the requirements of the app cannot be fulfilled using a web app. Web technologies are much better understood (both in terms of developing and deploying them) and give you a broader range of deployment options.

Web app pros:

- Can provide local controls/widgets for users to interact with, so the app can feel more responsive even if the server is remote and/or being accessed from a mobile device with restricted bandwidth. In comparison Citrix delivery introduces noticeable latency from mobile devices.
- A better deployment option for non-Citrix customers since they only need to setup a web server.
- Cost is probably less if the customer has no existing infrastructure. I'd only be developing for Citrix if all my customers already use it.
- Wider range of support for different client platforms, i.e. pretty much all devices have a browser - not everything has a Citrix Receiver.
- It's easier to support multiple form factors, e.g. PC, tablet, phone.

Citrix pros:

- You have more options in terms of the tools/SDKs/resources you can use to develop your app. You can use anything that can create a Windows desktop app.
- Better security. No sensitive data ever gets downloaded to the device.
- Often easier to integrate with legacy back end systems.